# Need a cookie to save the size of the font

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have written this code which resizes the fonts when the user clicks on 'increase' or 'decrease' and would like to set a cookie to save the fontsize of the browser for 5-7 days.

The jQuery is here:

```js
$('.fontInc').on("click", function() {
    // increase current size by 1
    currentSize = parseInt($('body').css('font-size')) + 1;

    if(currentSize <= 20)
        $('body').css('font-size', currentSize);
});

$('.fontDec').on("click", function() {
    // decrease current size by 1
    currentSize = parseInt($('body').css('font-size')) - 1;

    if(currentSize >= 12)
        $('body').css('font-size', currentSize);
});
```

Now I assumed that if I wrote `$.cookie("saveFontSize", currentSize, {path:'/', expires: 5});` then this would save the 'currentSize' for 5 days but as soon as you refresh the browser the font returns to default...

What am I doing wrong? Do you need to see the HTML?

Comment: and do you READ the font size stored in cookie? I do not see that in your code ...

Comment: i'm not sure I understand you, is it the same as inititating a function? ie writing in `$.cookie('saveFontSize');` ?

If so then I haven't done that because I didn't think you need it?

Comment: Did you check the cookie value by alert($.cookie("saveFontSize")) ??

Comment: @Rue $.cookie('name') is a getter and $.cookie('name', {a:b}) is a setter

Comment: As a side remark, you might want to read [that question](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/29294/should-i-have-a-text-size-widget-for-accessibility-on-a-charity-website) about this type of functionality.

Comment: @bartdude cheers - I agree with that question and the responses, issue is it's being asked of me for work. I still cannot get it to work at all the cookie is getting the correct value and I'm getting no errors in the console

Comment: Yeah I know how it is, business people saw this 10 years ago and still find it a top notch functionality... at least now you have some points to raise next time you're asked, although I don't think they're going to listen but who knows ? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you're missing the part where you read the cookie on pageload.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').css('font-size', $.cookie('saveFontSize'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work fine, however it seems that you don't set font value during the page load.

```
    $(function () {
        var fontSize = $.cookie("saveFontSize");
        if (fontSize) {
            $('body').css('font-size', fontSize + "px");
        }  
    });
```

Please note that if cookie is missing then font value will remain same